# Binding to an object property

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

For Xamarin iOS, is it possible to bind to a property of an object which is within the viewmodel.
E.g. if we have the following object:

```
public class MyObject: MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isHidden;
    public bool IsHidden
    {
        get { return isHidden;}
        set { isHidden;= value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsHidden}
    }
}
```

And the following ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
{
    public MyObject myObject;
}
```

With the following binding on the MyView site

```
this.CreateBinding(myLabel).For("Hidden")
.To<MyViewModel>(vm => vm.MyObject.IsHidden).Apply();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, we used it a lot of times in our apps.
MvvmCross refer this kind of bindings as "chained binding" if I remember properly.

But be sure to take care of invoking the MyObject.PropertyChanged event on the proper thread (main thread to update your view UI).
MvvmCross only handle invoking the PropertyChanged event on the main thread while you are at the ViewModel level (take a look at [MvxNotifyPropertyChanged](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/c306ba37afd9024f68b7a4f1fedcaf4cf7d01b8d/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.cs) object implementation)

The proper binding syntax in my case is something like (which I expect to be equivalent to yours...):

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
set.Bind(yourLabel)
   .For(v => v.Hidden)
   .To(vm => vm.MyObject.IsHidden);
set.Apply();
```

This code must be applied in your `MvxViewController`.

Comment: Hi @GGirard even if I set MyObject.IsHidden on the main thread using  InvokeOnMainThread(() => {}) it does not trigger the property change on the binding. Is the binding method valid as it is in the above code or do I need to do something special to optain chained binding?

Comment: Did you take a look at the console output to see if the binding is properly applied?
You can add more binding logs with `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.MvxBindingTrace.TraceBindingLevel = Cirrious.CrossCore.Platform.MvxTraceLevel.Diagnostic;`

Comment: Forgot to RaisePropertyChanged on MyObject :s thanks!

Comment: @GGirard is this possible without using mvvmcross or other package?

Comment: @SiddharthP binding capabilities depend on binding engine you are using (MvvmCross, Xamarin.Forms, Mvvm light toolkit, ...). I am only experienced with MvvmCross, therefore I can't help you with others solutions. But sampling it should be pretty straight forward! Good luck.